# Placing JSON data in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating an autocomplete form that fills in your location based on your zipcode. This is the code I have to get a JSON with the information based on my zipcode:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/nl/1012", true);
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(client.readyState == 4) {
        // alert(client.responseText);
        var jsonObj = [client.responseText]

    };
};

client.send();
```

Now I only need the location entry of the json. But for some reason I cant figure out how to aquire it in a variable. Basicly what I am aiming for is to get something like:

```
var location = 'Amsterdam'
```

Thanks!

Comment: This really depends on the returned data structure. @Johan this seems like a bad idea, this should be done in the callback as otherwise your code could expect a variable that is not set yet. A global would make this hard.

Comment: I completely agree with the callback idea, removed for clarity sake!

Comment: I would like to add that if you are only passing back one data point, you don't need to use JSON at all as JSON is for structured data. If you are only passing back a city name, just send it back as text and use the result directly. This saves you some processing time in javascript for parsing JSON and on the server side for compiling JSON. Its small, but slightly better.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked the response of requesting a GET to  `http://api.zippopotam.us/nl/1012` and this is the response:

```
{
    "post code" : "1012",
    "country" : "Netherlands",
    "country abbreviation" : "NL",
    "places" : [{
            "place name" : "Amsterdam Binnenstad en Oostelijk Havengebied",
            "longitude" : "4.9027",
            "state" : "Noord-Holland",
            "state abbreviation" : "NH",
            "latitude" : "52.3666"
        }
    ]
}
```

So you will need to do something like the following:

```
var jsonResponse= JSON.parse(client.responseText);
var locations=jsonResponse.places; //an array!
if (places.length) {
  var firstLocation=locations[0]['place name'];
}
```

Comment: This is correct, I would have to say that maybe it is better to not use JSON at all if you are only passing back a single data point, as JSON is used for structured data. Just read the plain text response that contains the city name only would be better as neither the server nor your local code would need to parse any JSON, saving some milliseconds here and there.

Comment: Check my update! the received JSON is not so simple as I thought

Answer (score 2):

Could you post what you get returned from XML request. 
To parse a json in javascript you could use:

```
var jsonraw = JSON.parse(jsonobj)
```

This way, you can select something from the json with:

```
var location = jsonraw['location']
```

Replace `location` with what you get returned from the json.

Comment: Thanks! So stupid I totally forgot the JSON.parse. But this did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.parse` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(client.readyState == 4) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(client.responseText);
    };
};
```

and it wouldn't hurt to wrap that with a `try`, just in case the server dose not return a valid json

Comment: This is correct, I would have to say that maybe it is _better_ to not use JSON at all if you are only passing back a single data point, as JSON is used for structured data. Just read the plain text response that contains the city name only would be better as neither the server nor your local code would need to parse any JSON, saving some milliseconds here and there.